# Referencing C struct without referencing a member

Tags: c, struct

```
typedef struct s {
  int x;
  int y;
} S;

typedef struct t {
  S s;
}

T t = {0};
T *pointer_to_T = &t;


printf("End address %x", pointer_to_T->s);
printf("Beginning address %x", &(pointer_to_T->s));
```

Based on my testing, pointer_to_T->s is the address of the end of the structure S

```
pointer_to_T->s - &(pointer_to_T->s) = sizeof(S)
```

What is the expected behaviour here? Or is this just a coincidence?

Comment: Structures don't decay to pointers like arrays do when passing them as arguments. It shouldn't print any address of the structure.

Comment: You need quotes round %x. (I tried to add these in an edit but StackOverflow wouldn't accept it because the edit was too small.)

Comment: @GavinSmith Just as well, I wouldn't have approved such an edit when reviewing it -- you shouldn't edit questions to correct the code (the OP can do it if it was just a copying error).

Comment: @mbratch: It's perfectly legitimate to pass a structure by value, even to a varargs function. It's not legitimate to pass it to `printf`, but that's a runtime error; it happens that printf doesn't understand the structure. Compiling with `-Wall` (on most compilers) will flag it as a warning, though.

Comment: I still get a `0` printed out from your first `printf` (after fixing the syntax error in your latest posted code ;)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expected behaviour here can range from printing garbage to [nasal demons](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html), because this behaviour is undefined. The `%x` specifier makes `printf` expect an integer but it gets a struct, so anything is possible. What's most likely happening here is that it would print `s.x`, but again it may as well spawn a one-way portal to [Петропа́вловск-Камча́тский](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petropavlovsk-Kamchatsky).

Comment: I've updated the code in the question to reflect exactly what is happening. I suppose it doesn't change the answer but is it really just a mere coincidence that it prints the address at the end of the struct S?

Comment: For me it prints `End address 0
Beginning address 28ff14` so it may very well be a coincidence. Or perhaps something with the order the struct is pushed onto the stack and then some. But really, it may just as well have eaten my tv. The thing with undefined behaviour is that it's very hard to predict since there are no rules for these situations.

Answer (score 0):

Structures element isnot  a pointer. It won't print any address of the structure. That would be just garbage value which you are considering as end address. Garbage is undefined.

**Structure elements are not pointer that way array is.**

%x – Print a hexadecimal integer